# Change background color in an input from ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code, where when selecting a value in the select returns a date to put in the input.

```js
$('#title1').change(function(){
  var data = {"title1":$('#title1').val(),
  "title":$("#title").val()};
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"./atribdatt1",
    dataType:"Json",
    data:data,
    success:function(callback){
      var data_array = callback;
      artdat = data_array
      $("#vali1").html(artdat);
      document.getElementById('vali1').value = artdat;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">NOME VISITANTE</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select name="title1" class="form-control" id="title1">
      <option></option>
      <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.Utente WHERE ativo = '1' AND codigo NOT IN ('701', '723') ORDER BY nome ASC";
      $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
      echo '<option value="'.$ln['codigo'].'">'.$ln['nome'].'</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="date" name="vali1" class="form-control" id="vali1" readonly="true">
</div>
```

I intended that if the returned date is less than two days from the current date, put the input in red.
This way it always returns only the date but does not change the color of the input.
Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for access styles from JavaScript DOM elements have a `style` prop. The names of styles in javascript is camelCase keys in `style`.
https://api.jquery.com/css/
Usage:

```
const element = $("selector") // or on vanilla document.querySelector('selector')
// ...
element.css('background', 'red') // vanilla - element.style.background = 'red'
```

Comment: I have the following if: `var currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); if(artdat < currentDate ){document.getElementById('vali1').value = artdat;}else{document.getElementById('vali1').value = artdat;}`. As I apply your code where the condition is true returns the date input in red.

Comment: not understand what do you mean

Comment: I mean that if the returned date is greater than the current date it returns normal, if the date is less than the current date it returns red

Comment: if (currentDate < artdat) {
    // ... do stuff
} else {
   // ...
   $('selector').css('background', 'red')
}

This?

Comment: Then, apply my answer ;). Good day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242858/discussion-between-junior-and-vitaliyirtlach).